# Align widget center with AppBar bottom edge

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need to align a widget's center with the appbar bottom edge.
So it will be located vertically half on the appbar and half on the page body.

Right now I've added the widget into the AppBar bottom: but it wont align with it's horizontal center line.

Currently It looks like this:

[image]

While i want that the **center** of the SelectEnvironment button along with the horizontal white line will 'sit' exactly on the bottom edge of the appBar

The code for the appBar is like this:

```
  class CustomAppBar extends AppBar {

     final Widget appBarActionButton;

     CustomAppBar({Widget title = AppUtils.EMPTY_TEXT_VIEW, this.appBarActionButton}): super(
        title: title,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        elevation: 0,
        bottom: PreferredSize(
            child: Stack( //The stack holds the horizontal line and the button aligned cente
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container( //This is the horizontal line
                  color: Colors.GeneralDividerGray,
                  height: 1.0,
                ),
                Align(
                  child: Container(
                      child: appBarActionButton, //This is the button widget
                      ),
               )
          ],
        ),
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(4.0)),
      );
 }
```

If there a better way to achieve this by taking it outside of the appbar it's ok with me as long it will give the same effect.

Comment: have you tried `centerTitle: true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `Stack` and `Column` like this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

typedef void OnWidgetSizeChange(Size size);

class MeasureSize extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final OnWidgetSizeChange onChange;

  const MeasureSize({
    Key key,
    @required this.onChange,
    @required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MeasureSizeState createState() => _MeasureSizeState();
}

class _MeasureSizeState extends State<MeasureSize> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(postFrameCallback);
    return Container(
      key: widgetKey,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }

  var widgetKey = GlobalKey();
  var oldSize;

  void postFrameCallback(_) {
    var context = widgetKey.currentContext;
    if (context == null) return;

    var newSize = context.size;
    if (oldSize == newSize) return;

    oldSize = newSize;
    widget.onChange(newSize);
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Size s;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
      children: [
        Column(
          children: [
            MeasureSize(
              onChange: (size) {
                setState(() {
                  s = size;
                });
              },
              child: AppBar(
                title: Text('title'),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - (s?.height ?? 0.0),
                child: Center(child: Text('body')))
          ],
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: (s?.height ?? 0.0) - 16.0,
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                    height: 32,
                    color: Colors.red[400],
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
                    child: Center(child: Text('Select Environment'))),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: As you see in my code, my AppBar is custom and has a bottom PreferredSized widget, this causing problems to Column to calculate it's height. When I use it with a standard AppBar it worked great!

Comment: This is cool, to avoid infinity height why not put column in a container and then give container infinity height and then give that column a minimum axis size.... that will make a column constrain its height to fit the children's height.

Comment: Sorry, doing this hasn't fixed the problem. Any CustomAppBar with a bottom  widget (a PrefferedSizeWidget ) wont rendered in the column.

Comment: If you put a widget in bottom of appbar, appbar's height will grow up, and if you set color of bottom appbar to transparent then bottom appbar will have color same to appbar's color

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use Slivers via a widget like below:

```
  ScrollController scrollController = new ScrollController();
  return Stack(
    children: [
      NestedScrollView(
        controller: scrollController,
        headerSliverBuilder: (context, value){
          return [
//            list of widgets in here
          ];
        },
        body: Container(
          // here, your normal body goes
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        top: 50.0,
        left: 100.0,
        child: Container(
          // your centered widget here
        ),
      )
    ]
  );
}
```

Instead of using a normal appBar, you have to use a SliverAppBar

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try when I need to use it in a Sliver, which is my next task

Comment: All the best pal